# kubectl auth can-i create deployments --namespace default --as root Always returns no

Tags: kubernetes, authorization

I am experimenting with API Access permissions using below command as explained in https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/

`kubectl auth can-i create deployments --namespace dev`

I am logged in as root so this gave 'Yes'.  But I wanted to confirm if it works with below as well:

`kubectl auth can-i create deployments --namespace default --as root`

However, it returned 'no'.  As per the documentation, the above command is used to check if other users have access to use 'create deployments' api.  I assumed that for root, it will always return yes.  I am still logged in as root and trying to verify the above.  Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Thanks,
Niti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were permissions granted directly to the username "root" or to a group the root user is a member of?

To check permissions including group memberships with --as, you also need to specify the user's groups with --as-group

For example, if the root user is in the system:masters group:

```
… --as=root --as-group=system:authenticated --as-group=system:masters
```

Comment: Thank you Jordan. I tried with what you provided and it works! While I am happy to get past this issue, I am trying to follow what you have mentioned as I have not yet come across this explanation in the documentation I followed.  I will try to read more.  Appreciate your help!